# copy file into svn

Tags: svn

I have a file in my desktop. I want to copy it into the directory on the Svn system. I have a question

- How can I copy file from desktop to svn ?
- How can I move a file into a directory on the svn ?

Whenever I have used cp, it gives error. "It is not a workable directory".

Answer (score 2):

> [svn import](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.import.html) PATH URL

Recursively commit a copy of PATH to URL

Answer (score 1):

SVN works with **working copies** and **repositories**.

You create a **working copy** by performing `checkout` on a **repository**, then you can `add` files or directories to your **working copy**, finally you `commit` your changes to the **repository** to make them persistents.

Answer (score 1):

A file can exist within a SVN repo without being part of it.

In order to get the file into the SVN, you need to use:

svn add filename

or the equivalent in your graphical interface.

The error your terminal gives you, has nothing to do with SVN, it's is because the directory you are trying to move your file to either is not a directory or does not exist (perhaps misspelled!?). Try using the tabulator-key to autocomplete the path when using CP, or use a graphical interface to move you file into the SVN repo.